# Passing JSON array to MVC Controller Action not working

Tags: arrays, json, asp.net-mvc-4

We want to pass a `JSON array` to an `MVC Controller Action`. The Action Takes a list of Cards as parameter. When we call the Action, the parameter is null.

This is the client-side code:

```
function PrintCards() {
    var CardsArray = [];
    CardsArray = GenerateArrayOfCards();
    //CardsArray has the desired data
    var errors = JsonResults('/Operator/PrintCards', 'Cards=' + CardsArray, 'Post');
    if (errors != '') {
        alert('Something went wrong!');
        return false;
    }
    alert('Cards got Successfully assigned.');
}
```

And on the server-side we have the following Action

```
Public Function PrintCards(Cards As List(Of Card)) As JsonResult
    Try
        PrintAllCards(Cards)
        Return Json(String.Empty, "application/json", UTF8Encoding.UTF8)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Json(New With {.error = "Something went wrong!"}, "application/json", UTF8Encoding.UTF8)
    End Try
End Function
```

The problem is that in the Action, Cards is null while in the view (client-side) the array has data. Is there any convert or something missing?

Comment: try this $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    traditional: true,
    url: "/Operator/PrintCards",
    data: { Cards: CardsArray}
});

Comment: @unique it is null (`Nothing` actually, cause it's VB) yet.

Comment: you are saying no data coming to controller? Did you tried HttpGet action filter ?